# subset of larger set is also a subset of sigma algebra created by he larger set.

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove this simple equation. $C_1 \subset C_2 \implies C_1 \subset \sigma(C_2), \sigma(C_2)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C_2$. 
Example I was imagining:
$X=\{1,2,3\}. C_2=\{1,2\},C_1=\{1\}. \sigma(C_2)=\{\phi,X,C_2,X-C_2\} $ But $C_1=\{1\} \not\subset \sigma(C_2) $. 
I might be missing something silly but I am not a math major so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you wanted to write that $C_1 \in \sigma (C_2)$ because $\sigma (C_2)$ is a set which has sets as elements...Your example is correct..so the statement is not true in general.